# "Unresolved overloaded function type" while trying to use for_each with iterators and function in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, g++

```
//for( unsigned int i=0; i < c.size(); i++ ) tolower( c[i] );
for_each( c.begin(), c.end(), tolower );
```

I am trying to use a `for_each` loop in place of the for loop for an assignment.

I am unsure why I am getting this error message:

```
In function âvoid clean_entry(const std::string&, std::string&)â:
prog4.cc:62:40: error: no matching function for call to âfor_each(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved   overloaded function type>)â
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Write:

```
for_each( c.begin(), c.end(), ::tolower );
```

Or :

```
for_each( c.begin(), c.end(), (int(*)(int))tolower);
```

I've faced this problem so many times that  I'm tired of fixing this in my code, as well as in others' code.

Reason why your code is not working :  there is another overloaded function `tolower` in the namespace `std` which is causing problem when resolving the name, because the compiler is unable to decide which overload you're referring to, when you simply pass `tolower` <sup>1</sup>. That is why the compiler is saying `unresolved overloaded function type` in the error message, which indicates the presence of overload(s).

So to help the compiler in resolving to the correct overload, you've to cast `tolower` as

```
(int (*)(int))tolower
```

then the compiler gets the hint to select the global `tolower` function, which in other ways, can be used by writing `::tolower`.

<sup>1. I guess you've written `using namespace std` in your code. I would also suggest you to not to do that. Use fully-qualified names in general.</sup>

---

By the way, I think you want to transform the input string into lower case, if so, then `std::for_each` wouldn't do that. You've to use `std::transform` function as:

```
std::string out;
std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), std::back_inserter(out), ::tolower);
//out is output here. it's lowercase string.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately this is a STL class & were not supposed to use transform yet.

Comment: If he wants to modify the input string in-place, he can provide his own function to `std::for_each`. [Like this](http://ideone.com/3V7CN).

Comment: @bluetickk: But you're using `std::for_each` anyway. Why can't you use `std::transform`?

Comment: Note too that this version of `tolower` has undefined behavior on most systems when passed a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code. The danger of importing the entire std namespace is that you don't necessarily know what you are getting. In this case, you have imported overloads of `std::tolower`.

Never type `using namespace std;`, even if your textbook or your instructor tells you to.

2) Since you are restricted from using `std::transform`, you could modify the string in place using `std::for_each`:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void
MakeLower(char& c)
{
  c = std::tolower(c);
}

int
main ()
{
  std::string c("Hello, world\n");
  std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), MakeLower);
  std::cout << c;
}
```