# namespace in C++ when using c function

Tags: c++, c, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unresolved overloaded function type c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531866/unresolved-overloaded-function-type-c)

Consider the code snippet below:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void test(){
    std::string str = "Hello World!";
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), tolower);
}
```

There is an error about `tolower` when compiling with G++: **unresolved overloaded function**.

If `using namespace std;` is removed, the code works fine.

Then, my questions are:

- What is the relationship between `namespace std` with C functions?
- What is the difference between `#include<ctype.h>` and `#include<cctype>`? Although both of them don't work in the example above.
- Why `std::tolower` also doesn't work? What's the difference between `std::tolower` and `tolower`?

Comment: [Looks relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup#Criticism).

Comment: Same problem is here with detail answer : [unresolved overloaded function type c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531866/unresolved-overloaded-function-type-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no relationship between `namespace std` and C functions.  But
your code isn't C, it's C++, so you also have to consider C++ functions.
Like `std::tolower`, for example, in `<locale>`.  Your problem is due to
a concurrence of things:

- One of the headers you include includes `<locale>`.  C++ headers are
  allowed to include other C++ headers, and which header includes which
  other header may vary from one implementation to the other, so the
  code you've written might compile with one compiler, and not with
  another.
- You're trying to pass the function as a pointer to function argument,
  to a function template where the argument is a template type
  parameter.  Simply put, in order to do overload resolution on
  `tolower` here, the compiler must match it to the type of the
  argument, and in order to know the type of the argument, the compiler
  must do template type deduction based on the exact type of the
  function, which it can only know once it has done overload resolution.

If you want the function in `<ctype.h>` (which you don't, since it would
result in undefined behavior), you can get it either by including
`<ctype.h>` (which guarantees that it is present in the global
namespace) and using `::tolower`, or by explicitly specifying the
overload you want, e.g. `static_cast<int (*)(int)>( tolower )`  (In this
particular case, `static_cast` doesn't mean type conversion, but
explicit overload resolution.)

In practice, of course, you don't do this sort of thing.  If you're
doing any text processing at all, you'll define all of the necessary
functions as functional object types, which avoid undefined behavior by
either converting the input to `unsigned char`:

```
struct ToLower
{
    char operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return ::tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) );
    }
};
```

or by using the functions in `<locale>` which *do* work with `char`:

```
class ToLower
{
    std::locale myLocale;   //  necessary to guarantee the lifetime of the facet.
    std::ctype const* myCType;
public:
    ToLower( std::locale const& loc = std::locale() )
        ; myLocal( loc )
        , myCType( &std::use_facet<std::ctype>( loc ) )
    {
    }

    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return myCType->tolower( ch );
    }
};
```

Finally, WRT your second question: the difference depends on the version
of C++ you're using and the compiler.  Globally, however: `<ctype.h>`
will introduce the functions into the global namespace; `<cctype>` will
introduce them into the namespace `std::`, and maybe (or maybe not) into
the global namespace.  (And your third question has already been
answered above: `std::tolower` refers to a set of overloaded functions
defined in `<locale>` and `<cctype>`; `::tolower` refers to a single
function defined in `<ctype.h>`, and just `tolower` is the equivalent of
`::tolower`, *unless* you've done `using namespace std`, in which case,
it will refer to the overload set of all of the functions mentionned
above.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the namespace operator to use the C version of `tolower` like this:

```
::tolower(); // nothing before '::' means look in the global namespaece.
```

This will force the compiler to look for a function that is not inside a specific namespace, which is the case for all C-based API.

As for why `std::tolower`doesn't work, I have no idea. [The example of cpp reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/tolower/) doesn't use `std::transform`, this might be the reason.

Comment: That's to say: `#include <ctype.h>` means global namespace, while `#include <cctype>` in `std` namespace?

Comment: Kind of, yes. But `std::tolower` is in `<locale>`, not `<ctype>` :-)

Comment: And as usual, that "reference" is wrong. It's in `<cctype>` according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower and I just checked myself with both of my files.

Comment: Ah, nice! `<locale>` overloads the function with an additional *locale* argument. You're absolutely right.

Comment: @Gui13, Ah, that explains it. I didn't find any mention of that overload in my `<locale>` and if you navigate to the other overload, it's put in the right section. Apart from that confusion, though, it *is* known to have errors.

Comment: Then why C++ cann't resolve tolower when `using namespace std`? Just because C++ template can't distinguish two overloaded function?

Comment: @Martin See the related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531866/unresolved-overloaded-function-type-c (Nawaz proposed it in the comments of your question)