# Can't sort list with custom comparator function

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I'm getting this compiler error when I try to sort my ingredients with my custom comparator.

```
kitchen.cpp: In member function ‘void Kitchen::printContents(std::ofstream&)’:
kitchen.cpp:172: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::list<Ingredient, std::allocator<Ingredient> >::sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/list.tcc:271: note: candidates are: void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::sort() [with _Tp = Ingredient, _Alloc = std::allocator<Ingredient>]
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/list.tcc:348: note:                 void std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::sort(_StrictWeakOrdering) [with _StrictWeakOrdering = bool (Kitchen::*)(const Ingredient&, const Ingredient&), _Tp = Ingredient, _Alloc = std::allocator<Ingredient>]
```

Here's the code that is causing it:

```
bool sortFunction(const Ingredient a, const Ingredient b)
{
    if (a.getQuantity() < b.getQuantity())
        return true;
    else if (a.getQuantity() == b.getQuantity())
    {
        if (a.getName() < b.getName()) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    else return false;
}

void Kitchen::printContents(std::ofstream &ostr)
{
    ostr << "In the kitchen: " << std::endl;

    ingredients.sort(sortFunction);

    std::list<Ingredient>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = ingredients.begin(); itr != ingredients.end(); ++itr)
    {
        ostr << std::setw(3) << std::right << itr->getQuantity() << " " 
        << itr->getName() << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: how are you defining sort? The error is saying that you don't have a matching call to it.

Comment: @TopGunCoder: `std::list` has a `sort()` function that takes a comparator.

Comment: Do you have any other function named `sortFunction`? Is `sortFunction` a non-static member of `Kitchen`?

Comment: Why do you have both `bool sortFunction(const Ingredient a, const Ingredient b)` and also `bool Kitchen::sortFunction(const Ingredient&, const Ingredient&)`?

Answer (score 3):

There may be another `sortFunction` somewhere (e.g. in `Kitchen`), which causes the above error.

Try

```
ingredients.sort(::sortFunction);
```

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531866/unresolved-overloaded-function-type-c).

Also, for good coding practice, you may want to change

```
bool sortFunction(const Ingredient a, const Ingredient b)
```

to

```
bool sortFunction(const Ingredient &a, const Ingredient &b)
```

The first is passes in a copy of the object, the second just passes a reference to it.

Comment: Are you sure that the reason?

Comment: I had it like that before and it was giving me the same error. : (

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have method in Kicthen called sortFunction, and compiler cannot choose proper one.
You can try this:

```
list.sort( ::sortFunction );
```

To resolve it, or if the function you provided suppose to be method of Kitchen class you need to fix that.

Btw:

```
if (a.getName() < b.getName()) return true;
else return false;
```

Is the same as:

```
return a.getName() < b.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you declare a member function `Kitchen::sortFunction`. Within another member function (such as `printContents`), that will hide the non-member function you want to use.

The error message suggests that this is the case; it is trying to instantiate `sort` for a member-function type `bool (Kitchen::*)(const Ingredient&, const Ingredient&)`.

If the member function is not supposed to exist, then remove the declaration. If it is, then either rename one of the functions, or refer to the non-member function as `::sortFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function is:

```
bool sortFunction(const Ingredient a, const Ingredient b)
```

But it should probably be:

```
bool sortFunction(const Ingredient &a, const Ingredient &b)
```

(Note the references)

Also, as already mentioned, your Kitchen class already has a function called sortFunction() and it's taking precedence, so either use ::sortFunction() or give each function a unique and more-descriptive name.

If Kitchen::sortFunction() *is* the one you're wanting, it'll need to be a static member function.